# Powershell output to a text file

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to run multiple ps script and write the outcome to a file. for example, below. I can add each line in () | out-file -append test.txt -width 120. The problem is I dont want title and under score. Just want the 1 line result.

```
Get-SPSite F969095A-2AAF-4CEC-A8C8-086606F58959 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "4C28F38A-CB0E-45B0-AB67-48D841D3897A"} | ft Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
Get-SPSite 7EB84F0A-68AD-43F4-A4CD-0C08DB955885 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"} | ft Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
Get-SPSite 7EB84F0A-68AD-43F4-A4CD-0C08DB955885 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "74FF7F0A-0D3D-47F1-8435-1F8597CF14D9"} | ft Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
Get-SPSite DC650388-F3F5-4F41-BA3D-121F3586D8B7 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "718A92B3-511D-43A6-9C5D-27CDAD1476E3"} | ft Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
Get-SPSite DC650388-F3F5-4F41-BA3D-121F3586D8B7 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "F968C3F3-E6A3-4CE8-99E8-A8B5F984AE9D"} | ft Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
Get-SPSite DC650388-F3F5-4F41-BA3D-121F3586D8B7 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "EAF72D1D-89B7-4F93-99EC-B2D8C3777369"} | ft Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
Get-SPSite DC650388-F3F5-4F41-BA3D-121F3586D8B7 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "A1972377-D1C3-4B52-8E3D-F84CD87D2ED6"} | ft Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
Get-SPSite 7C473090-F368-4D14-96B7-1EBA6ED064B4 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"} | ft Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
Get-SPSite 7C473090-F368-4D14-96B7-1EBA6ED064B4 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "D4951A83-2EDA-4556-BA3E-17A6E6674073"} | ft Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
Get-SPSite 7C473090-F368-4D14-96B7-1EBA6ED064B4 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "514304E5-11DD-4478-9F7D-280CF1A271F9"} | ft Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
Get-SPSite 7C473090-F368-4D14-96B7-1EBA6ED064B4 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "0D9CB0AC-5926-4F01-8B55-3DFAB3658D8B"} | ft Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
Get-SPSite 7C473090-F368-4D14-96B7-1EBA6ED064B4 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "A6162406-4858-4C11-A917-8F663CA635FD"} | ft Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
Get-SPSite 7C473090-F368-4D14-96B7-1EBA6ED064B4 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "8F2CB028-847B-4AE7-919B-C8CEFCFDFB3F"} | ft Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
Get-SPSite 7C473090-F368-4D14-96B7-1EBA6ED064B4 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "127A6FC4-0A56-4CE4-B437-E7810B5A0CD5"} | ft Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
Get-SPSite 1B33B7AB-4FDF-4E44-938D-3CDBF74DCC4E | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "789C6C33-5EAE-4DA7-9C28-4F965CD6C73B"} | ft Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below code (not fancy but its works, may a dev guy can help u with better code).

```
$d = Get-SPSite F969095A-2AAF-4CEC-A8C8-086606F58959 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "4C28F38A-CB0E-45B0-AB67-48D841D3897A"} |Select-Object Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
$d | Export-CSV -Append  "C:\Listpout.csv"
$d = Get-SPSite 7EB84F0A-68AD-43F4-A4CD-0C08DB955885 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"} | Select-Object Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
$d | Export-CSV -Append  "C:\Listpout.csv"
$d = Get-SPSite 7EB84F0A-68AD-43F4-A4CD-0C08DB955885 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "74FF7F0A-0D3D-47F1-8435-1F8597CF14D9"} | Select-Object Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
$d | Export-CSV -Append  "C:\Listpout.csv"
$d = Get-SPSite DC650388-F3F5-4F41-BA3D-121F3586D8B7 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "718A92B3-511D-43A6-9C5D-27CDAD1476E3"} | Select-Object Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
$d | Export-CSV -Append  "C:\Listpout.csv"
$d = Get-SPSite DC650388-F3F5-4F41-BA3D-121F3586D8B7 | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID –eq "F968C3F3-E6A3-4CE8-99E8-A8B5F984AE9D"} |Select-Object Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
$d | Export-CSV -Append  "C:\Listpout.csv"
```

You can save the scipt into the one PS1 file and run that file.

Comment: Thanks Waqas. It worked. Wish there was a way to not to export title and underline from each one of this. I guess i can import this in excel and clean it up. Thanks again.

Comment: @BettySmith Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you to solve your issue, Thanks!